# Are there dunder methods for python functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm just wondering are there dunder methods for python **functions**, to achieve something like this...

```
def f():
  ...

def g():
  ...

h = f + g

h()
```

Comment: What would `h = f + g` _do_?

Comment: Functions are objects, like everything else. You can write a class of callable objects that implements `__add__` if you want. Is that your requirement?

Comment: `f.__dict__` and `g.__dict__` exist along with other dunder methods....

Comment: probably there are modules which adds something like this. For example `coconut`  has [compose](https://coconut.readthedocs.io/en/latest/DOCS.html#compose) which allows `h = f..g` or more `h = e..f..g` -  but it is adds so many new things for `functional programming` so it is treated as separated language. See [coconut-lang.org](http://coconut-lang.org/)

Comment: @khelwood Yes, how to write __add__() like methods for python functions?

Comment: Write a class with a `__call__` method, that's where you can put function implementations; and an `__add__` method, that's where you write whatever (you haven't specified) you want `f + g` to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this( i don't advise you to do so), but it can get very fast very nasty :

```
def f():
    return 1

def g():
    return 2

class hc(object):
    def __call__( self, f, g):
            return f() + g()

h = hc()
print(h(f,g))
```

> 3

Good luck :)

Comment: ...what's the point of the `hc` class? Why not just `def h(f, g)…`?